# dart type assignment error when both sides are the same class

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two singletons: storage and pathFinder.  The storage creates an instance of pathFinder inside of it when it is initiated.  I wanted to create getPathFinder() to get the instance of pathFinder from storage in another class.

```
class Storage {
    static Storage? _instance;
    PathFinder _pathFinder = PathFinder();

// I left out the factory code

    PathFinder getPathFinder(){
        return _pathFinder;
    }
}
```

In another class I tried doing this:
`PathFinder _finder = storage.getPathFinder();`

The analyzer gives me this error:

````
A value of type 'PathFinder (where PathFinder is defined in d:\android\apps\bench\lib\pathfinder.dart)'
can't be assigned to a variable of type 'PathFinder
(where PathFinder is defined in d:\android\apps\bench\lib\pathFinder.dart)'.

Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'PathFinder (
where PathFinder is defined in d:\android\apps\bench\lib\pathFinder.dart)'
.dartinvalid_assignment
pathfinder.dart(4, 7): PathFinder is defined in d:\android\apps\bench\lib\pathfinder.dart

pathFinder.dart(4, 7): PathFinder is defined in d:\android\apps\bench\lib\pathFinder.dart```
````

Comment: Make sure PathFinder is not defined in multiple files? pathfinder.dart & pathFinder.dart?

Comment: Or if you're using a case-insensitive file system, make sure you consistently use the same case for the file paths to ensure that a single file isn't treated as two separate files.

Comment: I'd also recommend running flutter clean just to be sure.

Comment: I am coding this with VS Code, latest versions of dart and flutter on a windows 10 machine.  I ran Flutter clean but didn't seem to help.  Now I know that I can get a instance of pathFinder by just creating a reference directly.  But I see no reason why my code is generating an error.

Comment: @AndrewPenhorwood As pointed out already, your code is generating an error because you have referred to the same file with two different capitalizations, so it is treated as two different files that each declares a separate `PathFinder` class.  Pick one capitalization for the file path and *be consistent*.